# Service Worker sometimes installs without waiting

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I am using a [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox) in my Angular app and I am checking for Updates every 15 min so I can inform the user if a new version has been deployed.

When an update has been found, the new Service Worker is installed but not activated since this when I can prompt the user to reload the page:

[image]

When OK is clicked, I can inform my SW to skip waiting, since he has this EventListener:

```
addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    skipWaiting();
  }
});
```

This works well, **but from time to time (and I have not figured out why) the new SW is installed and activated right away without waiting** (even though no message was sent).

How can this be?

I implemented 2 ways to check for updates and react accordingly, both lead to the same problem.

**First way, the one from the official [Docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes):**

```
public async registerServiceWorker() {
  this.workbox = new Workbox('/sw.js', {});
  try {
    this.workbox.addEventListener('waiting', () => promptTheUser());
    this.swRegistration = await this.workbox.register();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('[SW] error registering service worker', e);
  }    
}

public async checkForUpdate() {
    return await this.swRegistration.update();
}

public activateNow() { // Called in the user prompt
    this.workbox.addEventListener('controlling', (event) => {
      window.location.reload();
    });
    if (this.swRegistration && this.swRegistration.waiting) {
      messageSW(this.swRegistration.waiting, { type: 'SKIP_WAITING' });
    }
}
```

**Second way, the one using [ServiceWorkerRegistration.onupdatefound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration#event_handlers) and [ServiceWorkerContainer.oncontrollerchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/oncontrollerchange):**

```
public async registerServiceWorker() {
    this.workbox = new Workbox('/sw.js', {});
    this.swRegistration = await this.workbox.register();
    this.swRegistration.installing.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
      if (this.swRegistration.waiting) {
        promptTheUser();
      }
    });
}

public async checkForUpdate() {
    return await this.swRegistration.update();
}

public activateNow() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', () => {
      window.location.reload();
    });
    if (this.swRegistration && this.swRegistration.waiting) {
      messageSW(this.swRegistration.waiting, { type: 'SKIP_WAITING' });
    }
}
```

The method registerServiceWorker() is called when the application starts.
Both ways should yield the same result, **but they do not work if state "controlling" is not reached. Instead, the new SW is just installed an activated.**

As a results, the page is never reloaded and my user prompt stays open...

Any ideas?

Comment: What you're describing sounds more like a browser bug, and less like an issue with Workbox or your SW. My understanding is that whenever a new SW is installed and there's already an active SW in control of at least one client, that new SW remains in waiting until `skipWaiting()` is called, or until all of the active SW's clients are closed. If you can reproduce different behavior, I'd recommend using https://crbug.com/new to file a Chrome bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, I found the problem. The reason why the "controllerchange" event was not fired is because **upon the first install of a service worker, if the page is not reloaded, the clients are not claimed**. I only found this because in my desperation I read the source code of [Workbox.ts](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/v6/packages/workbox-window/src/Workbox.ts) and stumbled upon this:

> Note: the first time a service worker is installed it will active
> but not start controlling the page unless `clients.claim()` is
> called in the service worker.

To me, this is a very important piece of information that is not highlighted enough in the docs (or the various state diagrams one can find online).

So I solved my problem by calling clients.claim() after the first install (so that it is transparent to the user), and all subsequent updates will trigger a notification for the user to reload the page.

Hope this helps others who run into this problem